# How to roll back a deployment to a previous revision automatically when deployment has crossed 'progressDeadlineSeconds'?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm working on deploying a docker image in kubernetes. The first time I deployed the container, I used:

```
kubectl apply -f <deployment_file>.yaml
```

and the container was successfully deployed in a pod.

Also, the deployment_file looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: publisher
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 300
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 900
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: publisher
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: publisher
        image: 123dev.azurecr.io/publisher:{{ci-build-number}}
        env:
          - name: ENVIRONMENT
            value: "dev"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

I have defined the 'progressDeadlineSeconds' attribute in the yaml file above.

To keep a track of the deployment, I used:

```
kubectl rollout status deployment.v1beta1.apps/publisher
```

Now if I want to update the container with a new image, I can again reuse the command

```
kubectl apply -f <deployment_file>.yaml
```

to apply the update.

But what if applying the update fails due to some reason (let's say the docker image is corrupt), is there a way to automatically trigger a rollback to the previous revision when - pods status is not set to 'running' OR the execution time crosses 'pregressDeadlineSeconds'?

Till now I haven't found a way to execute a rollback automatically. Thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

follow the below steps.

```
1. append the --record param to deployment, as shown below
kubectl apply -f <deployment_file>.yaml --record

2. kubectl rollout history deploy <deployment-name> to check deployment history. for example,
kubectl rollout history deploy mynginx
deployments "mynginx"
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
3         kubectl set image deploy mynginx mynginx=nginx:1.12.2
4         kubectl set image deploy mynginx mynginx=nginx:1.13.8


3. you can rollback to previous version using revision, say to revision 3
kubectl rollout undo deploy mynginx --to-revision=3
```

Answer (score 5):

After the `kubectl apply` command you can check if the deployment rolled out successfully or not and then, if necessary, the `kubectl rollout undo` command can rollback to the previous revision.
Also, you can use the `sleep` Linux command to wait some time before that.

On Linux:

```
sleep 900 && \
if [[ $(timeout 5 kubectl rollout status -f <deployment_file>.yaml) != *"successfully rolled out"* ]]; then     
    kubectl rollout undo -f <deployment_file>.yaml
fi > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`timeout 5` stops the `kubectl rollout status` if its stuck after 5 seconds.

`> /dev/null 2>&1 &` runs the command in the background and without terminal output.

Answer (score 3):

This is the steps which I follow to undo the rollout of a deployment

Here **client-depl** is the name of the deployment

Step.1 To get the list of history of a specific deployment use this command

```
kubectl rollout history deploy client-depl
```

after that you will get output like this.

[rollout history deploy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWZpB.png)

so let say I want to rollout the deployment  to REVISION 1 then use this command

```
$ kubectl rollout undo deploy client-depl --to-revision=1
```

after that you will get output like this

[deployment rollback image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PPvg.png)

congratulations you have successfully rollout the deployment to previous version. For any doubt please reply will happy to help you.

Comment: There is no reason to use images for textual output.